# How to handle + character while sending the url request to the web server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am facing problem by posting the request to the server with details including phone number with + character compulsory. then + character not displaying at server end.

```
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"name="]; 
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:profileObj.name];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&email="];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:profileObj.email];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&password="];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:profileObj.password];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&phoneno="];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:profileObj.phoneno]; // here my data is +919999999999
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&address="];
    curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:profileObj.address];
    curl = [curl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    NSString *escapedUrlString = [curl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];

    [self updateStatus];
    if (internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable) 
    {
        UIAlertView *reachbleAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error"
                                                   message:@"No Network Available. \n This Application requires network connectivity. "
                                                  delegate:self 
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [reachbleAlert show];   
        [reachbleAlert release];
        return;
    }
    else 
    {

        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL 
                                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                              timeoutInterval:10];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

        [pool release];

    }
```

I used below line:

```
 NSString *escapedUrlString = [curl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

before requesting to server. So Please help me any solution to handle + character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `+` is a legal character in a URL, so it is ignored by `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`  You should manually escape the `+` signs before putting it into the URL e.g.

```
...
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&phoneno="];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString: [profileObj.phoneno stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: @"+" with: @"%2B"]]; // here my data is +919999999999 
...
```

NB Not sure about the `%2B`. 2B or not 2B, that is the question.